# "He is loved", is 'loved' an adjective or a verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

> He is loved.

This is something that I've always kind of wondered.

In a sentence like this, is *loved* a verb or an adjective? Can it be considered either?

Comment: Related, actually it's identical, but I'd be happy to see what others think http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page