# Is mixed that is used in this sentence "paints are mixed well." an adjective?

Tags: grammar

Sometime I am Confused between the adjective and passive voice. For example:

> 1. window is broken?
> 2. window is broken?

The first example shows the state and the second example is in the passive voice. So my question is can I used mixed as an adjective in the following sentences:

> Paints are mixed well.

And is there any way that I can clear my confusion. And how many more verbs are there that behave like an adjective?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [verb or adjective in "The blue page is \*stapled\* to the red page"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page) The adjective vs verb-form question is a common thorny problem with many if not most verbs. An agent (broken **by** _Fred_) forces the verb analysis. In your case, the common compound (prenominal) adjective is well-mixed, though your variant is also acceptable.

Comment: What do you want your sentence to mean? If someone is stirring two colours of paint together, they are being mixed (verb). If you have plants of the same kind but with different coloured flowers, they are of mixed colours (adjective).

Comment: Here is a brief context that might describe my question. Suppose there were two paints in the room. And when I left the room and came back few minutes later. I found two paints were mixed together. So is here mixed an adjective or not?

Comment: If you were gone briefly, you are probably wondering who did that (the verb *mixed*, like mixed up or messed) to your paints, not "Wow, those colors do make a nice blend as one (the adjective *mixed*, like nicely combined)."