# MADE - a VERB or an ADJECTIVE in the example: "This car is MADE of steel." Please, help

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice

I understand that the word **MADE** is a verb by default, and this is an example with it in a passive voice:

"The cars are made of steel."

But can it be an adjective? As a characteristic of something, like in this example:

"This car is **made** of steel" or "This desk is **made** of hard wood"

Thanks

Comment: If "made" in your example were an adjective, we could modify it with "very" as in: *This car is **very made** of steel* or we would have the comparative form, e.g. “*This car is* **more made** / **mader**  *of steel **than** that one*” The term could stand alone as in "This car **is smart**" ---> "This car **is made**" However, not one of these examples with "made" is grammatical or idiomatic.

Comment: It's a **verb** as always. Just that *made of* is a set phrase, almost an idiom, meaning "produced using a material or a thing." Also, *made out of*, *made from*.  HTH.

Comment: See [passive voice - verb or adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page) for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot find the reference, forgive me, but here goes.

The verb in these cases is the word '*is*', not '*made*'. 
'Made of' works as an adjective to describe the nature of the car and the desk.
It is [very] old fashioned but still correct to say that the desk is '*of wood*' and that the car is '*of steel*'. The idiom *Made of* describes the fundamental nature of the object, not its process of construction or action of being made.

Comment: IS MADE is definitely the PV of the verb, but it does the function of an adjective.

Comment: The construction is referred to as a [stative passive](https://www.grammarbank.com/stative-passive-verbs.html).

Comment: I cede to your wisdom. I had not the time to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

sure.

There is the sentence structure **predicate adjective**.
(1) *The car is red.* (2) *The weather was nice.* (3) *English grammar is difficult.*

All verbs have a form called their **past participle**.
(1) to write --> *written* (2) to bake --> *baked* (3) to fly --> *flown*

Past participles can modify nouns, and thus be adjectives, such as:
(1) *the plays written by Shakespeare* (2) *the cakes baked by my mom* (3) *the b29 flown by the USAF*

So, technically speaking, these all follow **BOTH** the predicate adjective sentence structure, as well as the passive voice sentence structure:
(1) *The plays were written by Shakespeare.*
(2) *The cakes were baked by my mom.*
(3) *The b29 was flown by the USAF.*

Active voice:
(1) *Shakespeare wrote the plays.*
(2) *My mom baked the cakes.*
(3) *The USAF flew the b29.*

Comment: Am I any the wiser now?

Answer (score 0):

In traditional grammar, the example is analysed as a passive as follows:

1...This car.......is............made................ of ............steel"

...subject .......verb...past participle...preposition... noun

Noun Phrase.[...........verb...............]..[adverbial modifier]

A more advanced version would have

2...This car............ is........ made......... of ............steel"

...subject .........verb.....adjective... preposition... noun

Noun Phrase....verb......adjective....[adverbial modifier]

Noun Phrase....verb.....[........adjectival modifier...........]

The test for an adjective is often "adding 'very' and see if it makes sense. HOWEVER, this does not work with **ungradeable** adjectives, e.g. *"She was very pregnant." (wrong) and "made" is an ungradeable adjective.

> OED made(adj): Produced or obtained by making as distinguished in some way from other modes of origin or acquisition; resulting from human activity.
>
> 1981   A. B. Facey Fortunate Life 44  *The road was just a winding track—there were no made roads in those days.*

Comment: Please cite your sources.