# Past participle used verbially /adjectivally

Tags: grammaticality

How does one distinguish as to when a past participle is used verbially in passive voice or as adjective with verb 'to be' when the doer of the action(agent"by")is not given ? 
In many sentences it can be understood to be used either way 
Example-The flight was cancelled/delayed ('Cancelled'/delayed) can be interpreted to be used either way based on one's interpretation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [verb or adjective in "The blue page is \*stapled\* to the red page"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page) 'The front window was broken.'  is _well known to be inherently **ambiguous**._ << Sometimes, it is far easier than this to distinguish adjectival and verbal usages of -ed forms:

'On arriving back home, we saw that the front window was broken.' [adj] BUT 

'The front window was broken by the ball Gayle hit over the main stand.' [verb] >> _Only context can disambiguate here._

Comment: They are still verbs even if there is no _by_ phrase. Your examples denote an action, not a state, thus they cannot be adjectives.

Comment: You need context. Sometimes tense helps you frame it. *The airlines cancelled the flight.* (active) *The flight was cancelled [by the airlines].* (passive) *Now it is a cancelled flight.* (adj) *The flight is cancelled.* (adj)

Comment: Dear Edwin, Bill and Tinfoil,  Thanks for responding. The line between action and state appears blurred many a times and I don't find a definitive differentiator.

Comment: Dear Bill, How will you interpret the sentence "The door is locked/closed.It could be the state of the door and it could be locked/closed by someone .Thanks

Comment: Dear Edwin,  Do we have to live with this ambiguity as sought in my example? Even at times context doesn't make the distinction clear. Thanks