# How to know if a past participle form used in a sentence is the adjective for the next word or not?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, passive-voice, relative-clauses

I've read this sentence in a book:

> Like most languages, C# lets you define local variables, which are named elements inside a method that each hold a piece of information.

I can see this sentence in two ways, I can't get to know which one is the correct one:

1. *named* is the adjective of *elements*. So nothing is named "elements inside a method"! it is just saying that variables are *named elements* (each element has a name) which are declared inside a method and hold a piece of information.
2. *are named* is a passive verb, and the whole sentence means that variables are named "elements inside a method"

I myself think that the first one is correct, however I have to persuade someone who thinks the second one is correct. I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [verb or adjective in "The blue page is \*stapled\* to the red page"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page)

Comment: I'd say that 'named elements' is [attribute + referent] (cf 'landed gentry') and on the analysis I subscribe to, 'named' is an adjective (obviously a participial one, so strongly  connoting verbiness).

Comment: I see "named" as a verb, not an adjective, because it has none of the distinctive properties of adjectives. For example, it can't be modified by "very" and it can't occur as  complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" (*"It became quite named") or complex-transitive verbs like "find" (*"I found it quite named").

Comment: ... But then 'nuclear' would cause problems with these tests. Essentially, there are different schools here.

Comment: But there is no verb "nuclear", whereas there is a verb "name", hence the doubt about whether "named" is a participial adjective or a verb phrase.

Comment: ... Leading to a different analysis for 'talented' and 'gifted'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the sentence is ambiguous, and both readings 1) and 2) are possible. But the context makes it completely clear that 1) is the correct one here: local variables exist inside a method, and they are elements that have names.

To avoid this ambiguity, in case reading 2) was intended, the writer could have used quotation marks around *elements*: *which are named 'elements'...* This would have been advisable. But reading 2) was never intended, so it doesn't matter here.