# In "The car was parked", what part of speech is "parked"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In "The car was parked", what part of speech is "parked"?

I'm thinking adjective, but someone else thinks it's a verb.

Comment: Did you do any research? If you search this site you should get some relevant discussions. (E.g.: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page)

Comment: Thanks for the link! How did you find it? I indeed did search around, and was certain that a similar question would have been asked and answered somewhere, but could not easily find an example. A general search like "adjective or verb after linking verb" didn't help much either.

Comment: I don't remember my exact search terms, but perhaps "past participle" and "predicate adjective".