# Is it correct to say "keep the wire covered by a insulating layer" or "keep the wire being covered by a insulating layer"?

Tags: passive-voice

As suggested by the title, I want to use "keep" followed by some passive voices. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: When would you "keep a wire covered by an insulating layer"? You either use insulated wire or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the wire covered by **an** insulating layer.

Comment: People here are just not reading properly. When would you ever "keep a wire covered with an insulating layer"?  I think he means: Make sure to always use insulated wire.

Comment: @Lambie: Some more context would certainly help. It's not impossible ("To avoid it heating the experiment setup too much, keep the wire covered with an insulating layer of fibreglass wool") but as you say, absent any context, other interpretations seem more likely.

Comment: @psmears I truly doubt the OP meant anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Keep the wire covered **with** **an** insulating layer.

Or better:

> Keep the wire covered with a layer of insulation.

Comment: Think about the meaning just a tad. It's pretty senseless. You cover or do not cover something with "an insulating layer". It's not like it can be removed like a tarp over a woodpile.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have two options here if you want to use *keep*.

Why? Let's have a look at the definition of *keep* in the Oxford Learner's Dictionaries. There are 16 different entries under that definition, and if you examine them carefully, you will find that only entries 4 and 5 are relevant here.

*Stay* (entry 4). One possible structure is **keep + adj.**, which uses the adjectival passive *covered by an insulating layer* to express a **state**:

> Keep the wire **covered** by/with **an** insulating layer.

*Continue* (entry 5). The second possible structure is to **keep doing something**, which uses the gerund *covering  the wire with an insulating layer* to express an **action**:

> Keep **covering** the wire **with** **an** insulating layer.

For a deeper discussion of passive verbs (which describe an action) vs. adjectival passives (which describe a state), see the answer in the following thread: [verb or adjective in "The blue page is *stapled* to the red page"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page)

Reference: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/keep_1